# bash - get io statistics of the child process

Tags: linux, bash

I have a bash process which calls another child process (mysqldump) for example. I need to determine the io usage of this child process. I tried cat /proc/self/io but values for io are connected only with the parent process. But I need the data for the child process. I can determine the pid of the child process and try view /proc/[pid of child]/io but when should I do that? If I do mysqldump and then /proc/[pid of child]/ioб /proc/[pid of child] won't exist after the finishing of the child process. Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like a system administration problem. I think this might be better suited for serverfault.com.

Comment: `time -v your command and args` time uses the getrsuage() system call.

Answer (score 2):

You can probably use `strace` command as below to get that result.

```
strace -e trace=read,write -o ls.log ls
```

Here, `strace` will give the result for `ls` command. If you want to attach to particular process, use the `-p pid` option like

```
strace -e trace=read,write -o ls.log -p <child process PID>
```

More about [Strace Command Here](http://linux.die.net/man/1/strace)